# Customised data load in SSIS

Tags: ssis, etl

I am trying to design a SSIS Package, where if records in the files come for the first time than

load it to primary table, 
else to be load to secondary table.

files from different customer has unique customer id.

i am not sure if it is possible in SSIS.... can anyone please help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, could you explain the task in more detail? file type, values, tables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a lookup step in your dataflow, you can compare the data to the table1, if the data does not exist, put it in table1 if so put in table2

Answer (score 1):

You can read data in staging table and then compare ID from staging table with the ID in target table, if matches then insert in secondary table else insert into primary table.